# How to create / Write STDF file with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, automated-tests

I'm Trying to convert .txt data file to STDF (ATE Standard Test Data Format, commonly used in semiconductor tests) file.

Is there any way to do that?
Are there any libraries in Python which would help in cases like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use this - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pystdf/1.0.0

Comment: can I also write STDF file using pystdf?
From what I've read in the following link- It doesn't say so.
@DineshPundkar

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Semi-ATE STDF](https://github.com/Semi-ATE/STDF) library:

It supports only ver. 4. You can use conda-forge or pypi to install it.

Answer (score -1):

It is of course possible since Python is Turing complete.  However, you should use one of the available open source or commercial libraries to handle the STDF writing if you are not familiar with STDF. Even one mis-placed byte in the binary output will wreck your file.
It is impossible to say whether an existing tool can do this for you because a text file can have anything in it.  Your text file will need to adhere to the tool's expectations of where the necessary header data (lot id, program name, etc.), test names and numbers, part identifiers, test results and so on will be in the text file.

Comment: The question itself is off-topic (asking for a tool/framework recommendation). That said: you didn't answer the question. You just told the OP about python and how to use a tool/library.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear, but I told the OP that you can't usefully answer the question because it is too vague because a text file could have any kind of format whereas specific Python or other libraries will have specific input format requirements.